# Stackdriver group log statements with same operation id

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to associate multiple log statements (which are log statements for the same HTTP request but created by different classes) based on the operation id. The log statements which are to be grouped have the same operation id.
I am using jsonPayload for the log statements.
I am using latest version for google-fluentd for logging.
Can anyone please let me know if there is anything else that is required for grouping the log statements in stackdriver?

[Documentation for LogEntryOperation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogEntryOperation)